# Baking the arrays on screen with Processing

Tags: java, arrays, processing

I like working with Processing array functions but when I draw things using this function, I realize it's storing every single drawn shape in the memory, which is causing spikes in CPU. (Especially when it goes up to a few thousands)

How to bake the drawing then remove the array objects on mouserelease? I mean, can Processing behave those objects as a single image after every stroke then I'd clear the array using `.remove(0)` function?

Here's my code:

```
ArrayList <Drawing> drawings = new ArrayList <Drawing>();

void setup() {
  size(400, 400);
  background(255);
  colorMode(HSB);
}

void draw() {
  background(255);
  for (int i=0;i<drawings.size();i++) {
    drawings.get(i).display();


  }

  println(drawings.size());
}

void mouseDragged() {


  drawings.add(new Drawing(mouseX, mouseY));

}



class Drawing {
  float x, y, r;
  color c;

  Drawing(float ax, float ay) {
    x=ax;
    y=ay;
    r=random(2, 20);
    c=color(random(100, 200), 255, 255, 88);
  }

  void display() {
    noStroke();
    fill(c, 100);
    ellipse(x,y, r, r);
  }
}
```

Comment: If you simply need to draw look at [`createGraphics()`](https://processing.org/reference/createGraphics_.html). If you need to access the paths later look at [`createShape()`](https://processing.org/reference/createShape_.html) (eg `drawings = createShape(GROUP);`...`drawings.addChild(createShape(ELLIPSE,x,y,w,h));`, etc.), also see **Processing > Examples > Demos > Performance > StaticParticlesRetained**  (see differences between the default (`JAVA2D`) renderer and `P2D` passed to `size()`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to store the objects into the ArrayList only while the mouse is pressed (drawing new objects) and just have all the old objects to be static on the background out of the ArrayList you can do something like this:

```
ArrayList<Drawing> drawings = new ArrayList();
boolean flag = false;

void setup()
{
  size(400, 400);
  background(255);
  colorMode(HSB);
  loadPixels();
}

void draw()
{
  updatePixels();
  if(flag)
  {
    for(Drawing drawing : drawings)
    {
      drawing.display();
    }
  }
  println(drawings.size());
}

void mouseDragged()
{
  flag = true;
  Drawing drawing = new Drawing(mouseX, mouseY);
  drawings.add(drawing);
}

void mouseReleased()
{
  flag = false;
  loadPixels();
  drawings = new ArrayList();
}

class Drawing
{
  float x, y, r;
  color c;

  Drawing(float ax, float ay)
  {
    x=ax;
    y=ay;
    r=random(2, 20);
    c=color(random(100, 200), 255, 255, 88);
  }

  public void display()
  {
    noStroke();
    fill(c, 100);
    ellipse(x,y, r, r);
  }
}
```

The function *loadPixels()* stores into the *pixels[]* array all the pixels of the screen, while *updatePixels()* draws the pixels in *pixels[]* on the canvas. This way you can just empty your ArrayList every time the mouse is released and, even though when the ArrayList gets some thousands of elements you still get some CPU spikes, when the mouse is not being dragged or the ArrayList has less than a couple thousands of elements it is less CPU consuming.

Comment: Yes, I need them as objects until drawing finishes, they're going to interact with each other till mouse is released.

Comment: Please clarify your doubts before posting a solution.

Comment: @oferdofer what if you stored them into the ArrayList, but showed them on the screen like in the code proposed here? (Edited the code like this).

Comment: @RiccardoChimisso if I store them in the array list, it's causing CPU problems after a while as I mentioned. All I'm asking is a way to get them drawn without so many objects stored in the background. I'm open to other methods.

Comment: @oferdofer just storing them is causing you CPU problems? Isn't looping through the whole ArrayList 60 times per second, drawing all the objects in it, causing you problems? Indeed I tried using my code and reaching a size of about 11k elements, and the process never went over 2% of CPU usage, it mostly stayed under 0.5%. Then I edited the code by looping through the whole ArrayList in the draw() method to draw the objects in it, instead of drawing them in the mouseDragged() method. This time the CPU usage, after reaching a size of about 11k, went up to 17%, and never under 15.5%.

Comment: @RiccardoChimisso You don't get me. Arrays draw things and store them in the memory, which is what I want while drawing as I want to be able to adjust their positions, their interactions etc only while drawing! After releasing the mouse I'd like them to be rasterized which means they won't be acting as circles but a complete rasterized image because I'll draw another array of circles later, which I assume is going to be more CPU friendly. If I don't bake them on the background, all new circles are going to be added to the array and slow down the sketch. There are many apps using this method.

Comment: @oferdofer oh okay, I think I get it now. I'll update the answer, tell me if it's what you want.

Comment: @RiccardoChimisso Thanks a lot. I might need to talk to you in the future. Where can I talk to you?

Comment: @oferdofer yeah, sure. This is my email: riccardo.chimisso@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to access the drawings objects later (say to change properties), you can simply cache the rendering onto a separate [PGraphics layer](https://processing.org/reference/createGraphics_.html):

```
PGraphics drawings;

void setup() {
  size(400, 400);
  colorMode(HSB);

  drawings = createGraphics(width, height);
  // use drawing commands between beginDraw() / endDraw() calls
  drawings.beginDraw();
  drawings.background(255);
  drawings.colorMode(HSB);
  drawings.noStroke();
  drawings.endDraw();
}

void draw() {
  background(255);
  // PGraphics extends PImage so you can render it the same way
  image(drawings, 0, 0);
  println((int)frameRate); 
}

void mouseDragged() {
  drawRandomCircle(drawings, mouseX, mouseY);
}

void drawRandomCircle(PGraphics layer, float x, float y){
  float diameter = random(2, 20);
  layer.beginDraw();
    layer.fill(color(random(100, 200), 255, 255, 88));
    layer.ellipse(x, y, diameter, diameter);
  layer.endDraw();
}
```

Otherwise you can make use of [PShape](https://processing.org/reference/createShape_.html):

```
PShape drawings;

void setup() {
  size(400, 400, P2D);
  smooth();
  background(255);
  colorMode(HSB);
  // create a PShape group to append circles to later
  drawings = createShape(GROUP);
}

void draw() {
  background(255);
  // render PShape
  shape(drawings);

  println(drawings.getChildCount() + " shapes at ~" + (int)frameRate + "fps");
}

void mouseDragged() {

  drawings.addChild(addRandomCircle(mouseX, mouseY));

}

PShape addRandomCircle(float x, float y){
  float diameter = random(2, 20);

  // create an ellipse PShape with the desired dimensions, position, fill and (no)stroke
  PShape circle = createShape(ELLIPSE, x, y, diameter, diameter);
  circle.setFill(color(random(100, 200), 255, 255, 88));
  circle.setStroke(false);

  return circle;
}
```

As mentioned in my comment check out **Processing > Examples > Demos > Performance > StaticParticlesRetained**

If you need later access to each added circle/drawing you can iterate over the parent PShape:

```
// iterate though nested PShapes
  for(int i = 0 ; i < drawings.getChildCount(); i++){
    // access each PShape
    PShape drawing = drawings.getChild(i);
    // access PShape properties
    println("drawings[" + i + "] has " + drawing.getVertexCount() + " vertices");
  }
```

Should you need extra functionality (like a separate property to animate), you can always [extend](https://processing.org/reference/extends.html) PShape: re-use what's already there add what you need on top:

[image: Processing PShape custom ellipse]

```
PShape drawings;

void setup() {
  size(400, 400, P2D);
  smooth();
  background(255);
  colorMode(HSB);
  // create a PShape group to append circles to later
  drawings = createShape(GROUP);
}

void draw() {
  background(255);
  // use custom functionality
  for(int i = 0 ; i < drawings.getChildCount(); i++){
    // cast from PShape superclass to the custom Drawing subclass
    Drawing drawing = (Drawing)drawings.getChild(i);
    // use the custom functionality
    drawing.update(i);
  }

  // render PShape
  shape(drawings);
  println(drawings.getChildCount() + " shapes at ~" + (int)frameRate + "fps");
}

void mouseDragged() {

  drawings.addChild(new Drawing((PGraphicsOpenGL)g, mouseX, mouseY));

}

class Drawing extends PShapeOpenGL{

  float x, y, diameter;

  Drawing(PGraphicsOpenGL pg, float x, float y){
    // call PShape super constructor setting this as a primitive (e.g. POINT, LINE, RECT, ELLIPSE, etc.)
    super(pg, PShape.PRIMITIVE);
    setKind(ELLIPSE);

    diameter = random(2, 20);
    // set (ellipse) shape parameters 
    setParams(new float[]{x, y, diameter, diameter});
    // fill  
    setFill(color(random(100, 200), 255, 255, 88));
    // disable stroke
    setStroke(false);

    // remember original position
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }

  // a custom functionality on top of PShape
  void update(int index){
    float offset = map(sin((frameCount + ((index+1) * 10)) * 0.025), -1.0, 1.0, -15, 15);
    // reset transformations
    this.resetMatrix();
    // translate backwards
    this.translate(-x, -y);
    // translate back + the offset
    this.translate(x + offset, y);
  } 

}
```

For the full list of functionalities see [PShape javadocs](http://processing.github.io/processing-javadocs/core/processing/core/PShape.html)

Starting with the simplest thing though. If you want to simply render many shapes without changing them later PGraphics will do the trick

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate that.